# Regex will not detect textmeshpro text

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

I am new to regular expressions and I am trying to implement one into my unity game, to detect if a player's name uses only lowercase letters. However, no matter what I try, it will not accept any entirely lowercase strings from a textmeshpro gameobject.

```cs
    public TextMeshProUGUI nameHolder;
//...Other functions...
public async void UpdateHighScore()
{
    name = "test";//works fine
name = nameHolder.text.Trim(); //does not work

    if (name.Length <= 7 && name.Length > 0)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(name, "^[a-z]{1,7}$"))
        {
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, new AmazonS3Config
        {
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest1,
            ServiceURL = "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        });

        PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = filePath,
            ContentBody = Highscore.ToString() + "," + name
        };

        try
        {
            await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
            Debug.Log("Highscore updated and uploaded successfully!");
                    text.text = "Name entered!";
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error updating highscore: " + e.Message);
        }
    } else {
            text.text = "Only use lowercase letters";
              Debug.Log(name);
    }
} else {
    Debug.Log(name.Length);
    text.text = "Name to long or short";
}
    }
}
```

I tested the regular expression in sites like regex101, and it was working. I also tried switching to

```cs
str.All(char.IsLower);
```

But I had the exact same issue. I have asked chatGPT, google bard, and bing chat (GPT-4) But they all say the same things, and none of it is working. I added the entire funciton in case this helps too.

Comment: There is never need to escape an input string. Replace `Regex.Escape(name)` with `name`. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I don't know C#, so pardon me if this is a stupid question: How can `name.Length` be negative, or, in other words, why is the `name.Length > 0` check necessary?

Comment: So for the first question, sorry I dont know how to reply, that is what google bard said to add, and I figured that it couldnt hurt, but for the Regex.Escape, it still does not work without that, so I thought possibly it would do something. I dont know why I trusted google bard, and for the second question I just didnt want it to be an empty string, I could have just checked if it was not zero as well.

Comment: @InSync strings can have zero length. The check is for strings that have at least one but at most seven characters.

Comment: @Julian Ah yes, thanks. Stupid me needs some sleep.

Comment: Provide an example that isn't working.  Note that your `Debug.Log(name)` makes it really difficult to know if there were non-printing characters or trailing whitespace in the input --- the function will correctly reject such inputs, but then the logfile will mislead you into thinking it should have succeeded.

Comment: I had no Idea! Thank you so much! There is probably some whitespace but I thought I would be able to see that in the console. Thank you!

Comment: What is in `nameHolder.text`? Can you put a breakpoint and observe the actual string?

Comment: @Julian Its just, "test" or anything that the user inputs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why aren't you using the TMP regex ? What I mean is, why are you coding it when there is already built in support for it that requires **zero** code?

Comment: Please strip all irrelevant code like all the amazon stuff, debug statements, try/catches/... and keep only the relevant code to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe I figured it out. The TMP text seems to have some invisible characters at the end of it that are not deleted by the .Trim() function. When I view the data in plain text, the word, "gamer" becomes, "gamerâ€‹". Therefore, the regex does not match the last characters and is found false.